# Get HTML portion of the site angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a view

```
<section ui-view id="main"></section>
```

Now inside this view template is loaded with this

```
<button ng-click="doSomething($('#main'))"></button>
```

But

```
$scope.doSomething = function(data){console.log(data)};
```

is undefined.

My task is to get part of the site content and transfer it to special RESTFul API to generate PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass the selector to the function, and then get the jQuery object from there, no?

```
<button ng-click="doSomething('#main')"></button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(selector) {
                       console.log( $(selector) );
                     };
```